# OpenVPN client breaks remote access to web server

Tags: linux, nginx, openvpn

I have an issue where whenever I use OpenVPN client to connect to the remote server to (obviously) set up a VPN tunnel, I can no longer see my nginx server. I can connect on the local network but it seems like it's dropping any remote access to the nginx web server. The VPN tunnel works perfectly. The nginx works fine as long as OpenVPN client isn't running but it stops immediately if I set up the VPN session. Is this something that can be fixed via iptables or routing settings? The system is x86_64 Fedora 19; eth0 is the network card, and tun0 is the vpn interface. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why in the world did someone downvote this? If I worded the question wrong at least give an honest criticism and explain why.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of googling and trying things, this worked for me:

Edit your ovpn file. E.g.: my.ovpn, the one you use like this: `openvpn --config my.ovpn`.

Before any certificate stuff enter:

```
route-nopull
route 0.0.0.0 128.0.0.0
```

This causes outgoing connections to go over the VPN while inbound connections use the defaults.

Took me ages to figure out these 2 lines.

Comment: Confirmed that this worked for me. I have a Freshtomato router which allows you to tunnel everything through an OpenVPN client, and in its "Custom Configuration" in the "OpenVPN Client Configuration" I typed those two lines. My symptom was that, after enabling the tunnel, two websites I'm hosting would no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenVPN server is likely sending the `push "redirect-gateway <if_name>"` option to your clients.

In this situation, the client's default gateway is pointing through the VPN tunnel. If the network on the VPN server side of things is not configured to NAT traffic from the VPN clients back out to the internet, then the only hosts they'll be able to access are those directly accessible on the VPN server network.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old issue, but similar problems, despite my online search, have not received a good solution.

The problem the asker is raising is that Nginx running on the OpenVPN client will not be accessible from outside when the OpenVPN client is activated. The reason for this phenomenon is that the responding data packets of Nginx are sent to the OpenVPN tunnel (usually the tun0 interface), and therefore cannot be received by the web client from the eth0 interface. In fact, from the perspective of IP routing, if my server is A and the IP of the web service requester the is B, B may also be the external target service provider that A is trying to access. For transport layer routing, A's web service response to B and A's actively sent request to B are indistinguishable. From this perspective, it seems impossible to achieve separate routing for inbound and outbound traffic.

However, we actually have a breakthrough point: the web service always communicates with the requester using a fixed port on the local machine (usually 80 and 443), so we can distinguish inbound and outbound traffic by the port.

First, we run the following command:

```shell
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

In this command, we will instruct the routing table to observe the packets sent from local ports 80 and 443 and give these packets a specific tag (--set-mark 1). Then we run the following command:

```shell
ip route add default via [gateway addr of eth0] dev eth0 table 100
```

This command will create a new routing table called "table 100" and then add a default route to this table, directing traffic to the original gateway through eth0 interface. Then we run

```shell
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
```

This command will route packets with tag 1 using the "table 100" routing table. After running the above configuration, the web service can be accessed normally.